# "Unresolved function or method" with Passport.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

After setting up passport.js and mongoose authentication, I am consistently getting the "Unresolved function or method" on all of my relevant statements.

[image]
[image]

I tried invalidating chaches and restarting along with other workarounds, however, the problem has persisted.

My user.js:

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

//create user schema and model
var User = new Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    studentID: String,
    grades: [{
        subject: String,
        grade: String
    }]
});

User.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model('user', User);
```

> When I run the server, I also get the error:

`TypeError: passport.serialize is not a function`

Comment: pretty pictures, useless, but pretty - I take it `models/user.js` is something you wrote - you probably wrote it wrong - who can say, post the code if it's yours (not a picture of it)

Comment: @JaromandaX the pictures are included solely to show that webstorm is not recognizing the methods, my apologizes

Comment: I understand, but if you want help with code, post **your** code that is probably wrong (again, assuming models/user.js is your code)

Comment: @JaromandaX I updated to include my user.js

Answer (score 0):

user.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

//= ===============================
// User Schema
//= ===============================
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    lowercase: true,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
  });


// Pre-save of user to database, hash password if password is modified or new
UserSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  const user = this,
    SALT_FACTOR = 5;

  if (!user.isModified('password')) return next();

  bcrypt.genSalt(SALT_FACTOR, (err, salt) => {
    if (err) return next(err);

    bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, null, (err, hash) => {
      if (err) return next(err);
      user.password = hash;
      next();
    });
  });
});

// Method to compare password for login
UserSchema.methods.comparePassword = function (candidatePassword, cb) {
  bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, this.password, (err, isMatch) => {
    if (err) { return cb(err); }

    cb(null, isMatch);
  });
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

passport.js

```
const passport = require('passport');
const User = require('../models/user');
const config = require('./main');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local');

// username field is now email
const localOptions = {
  usernameField: 'email'
};

// set up the local login strategy
const localLogin = new LocalStrategy(localOptions, (email, password, done) => {
  User.findOne({ email }, (err, user) => {
    if (err) { return done(err); }
    if (!user) { return done(null, false, { error: 'Your login details could not be verified. Please try again.' }); }

    user.comparePassword(password, (err, isMatch) => {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!isMatch) { return done(null, false, { error: 'Your login details could not be verified. Please try again.' }); }

      return done(null, user);
    });
  });
});

passport.use(localLogin);
```

Answer (score 0):

So, now, you just need to create a controller to handle the business logic for user registrations and so on. For example,

*** UserController.js ***

```
// other functions

// register
export function register() {
  if (!req.body) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'All Fields Required.' });
  }

  const user = new User(req.body)

  user.save((err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).json({ err });
    }
    res.status(200).json({ user });
  })
}
```

***router.js***

```
// other important things to require
const passportService = require('./config/passport');

// Middleware to require login/auth
const requireLogin = passport.authenticate('local', { session: false 
});

// your routes go here and you can access requireLogin now, like so:

router.get('/users/:id', requireLogin, getUserById);
router.post('/users', register);
```

Hope this helps. Not trying to make you change your codebase but this is a better way to do what you want to do.

Comment: I appreciate the responses but my problem isn't with the setup, it's the "Unresolved function or method" error

Comment: Adding a link would probably help. What you gave is very little to go off of.

Comment: You have things setup wrong. The passport-local-mongoose repo also has a blog tutorial on getting started with the library. I'd check it out. You are essentially initializing Passport in your app.js file but you aren't actually doing anything with it. In your routes/index.js, you should be doing things like: (something like it, anyway)

passport.authenticate('local', (req, res) => {
  res.redirect('/');
});

Comment: Check out the blog Michael created for this. It can be seen at:

http://mherman.org/blog/2013/11/11/user-authentication-with-passport-dot-js/#.WQF28VMrKAw

Comment: thanks I'll make sure to check that out. Is it my setup that's causing the `"Unresolved function or method"` problem? Because even if my setup as a whole is incorrect, shouldn't the methods still be recognized by webstorm?

Comment: A few more comments... You should never put environment variables in your code. Your database string should be an actual variable on Heroku or use a library like .env for that type of stuff, especially when you don't have the repo private. Also, you shouldn't camel case your endpoints or include the HTTP method. It's not RESTful. Not trying to be a jerk but if you want to, check out my repo @ https://github.com/iamclaytonray/node-blog-api

Comment: Well, take a look at the pictures. I've never used Webstorm but when you get an underline on anything, it means something's wrong. VS Code does the same thing, which is my IDE.

Comment: Thanks again, I'll take a look. I'm in high school and just learning node.js (android background) which is why my code probably doesn't follow convention. Sorry for all the trouble. Based on what you saw, did anything appear as though it might be causing the error? For example, a simple statement like `passport.initialize();` shouldn't cause an error by itself...

Comment: I've been programming for just over a year so I don't want you thinking I'm on top of it, haha. I'm 20 so we are not far from age. Anyway, I am really not sure. I would say that the problem is the same as I listed before. You are calling things that don't exist, which could possibly be messing with Passport. For example, passport.register() is not an actual method, from what I saw. That's a sure why to break things at runtime. I can't say anything for certainty because you don't have things set up to be properly tested. (Like views for login, register, etc)

Comment: I will add that after I learned about TypeScript, I vowed to never write regular JavaScript again. (Working my way up to TypeScript with React but that's a different story). TypeScript gives you a lot of benefits and one of the best features of it is that TypeScript will catch a lot of problems at compile time. I suggest looking into it. If I ever wrote enterprise-grade software with JavaScript, I would write it in TypeScript. Just something to think about. :)

Comment: I'll look into it. Just curious: in the link you sent, Michael Herman uses the function `Account.register` in his `routes.js` yet I see no declaration of this function. Is it included within `mongoose-local`? (in reference to your "`passport.register()` is not an actual method" comment)

Comment: If you look at his routes.js, you will see a post request to /register. In that request, he handles the business logic for user registration. I copied/pasted the same code from his blog post at routes.js, lines 14 - 24:

`app.post('/register', function(req, res) {
    Account.register(new Account({ username : req.body.username }), req.body.password, function(err, account) {
        if (err) {
            return res.render('register', { account : account });
        }

        passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, function () {
          res.redirect('/');
        });
    });`

Comment: I'd be happy to help you out more. My email is iamclaytonray@gmail.com. I just don't get on SO too often